# Need help understanding this particular code

Tags: c#

```
int distance = s.ToCharArray()
                .Zip(t.ToCharArray(), (c1, c2) => new { c1, c2 })
                .Count(m => m.c1 != m.c2);
```

This code id to calculate the hamming distance but can't seem to understand how it does it (i'm a beginner in c# )

Comment: What is the specific part you need help with? Please share the effort you did with us

Comment: Hint - the `Zip` and `Count` functions are under Linq

Comment: hello gilad i'm having a problem to determine which data strucuture  does the hamming distance uses

Answer (score 1):

Given two strings of the same length, the Hamming distance is defined as the number of different characters at each position, e.g. *best* and *test* have distance 1.  The code you provided uses the `Zip` function to create a list of character pairs for each position (index) in the string. Lets go through the code one by one:

Assuming you have these two strings:

```
string s = "test";  
string t = "best";
```

`string.ToCharArray()` converts them to arrays of `char`:

```
char[] sChars = ['t', 'e', 's', 't'];
char[] tChars = ['b', 'e', 's', 't'];
```

Then, `sChars.Zip(tChars, (c1, c2) => new { c1, c2 })` applied on those, creates a list of char pairs (actually anonymous classes containing two `chars`):

```
var zippedChars = [
     {c1 = 't', c2 = 'b'},
     {c1 = 'e', c2 = 'e'},
     {c1 = 's', c2 = 's'},
     {c1 = 't', c2 = 't'}
];
```

Then `zippedChars.Count(m => m.c1 != m.c2)` counts where the first character from the pair is not equal to the other one:

```
var distance = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much i appreciate your help